# How to escape from the standard output redirection in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager, stringio

I want to process a live output of a thirdparty script, printing some lines that match a pattern but skipping others:

```
def thirdparty_code():
    from random import choice
    stuff = ['keep: important stuff', 'ignore: boring stuff']
    while True:
        chosen_line = choice(stuff)
        print(chosen_line)
```

I use `redirect_stdout` (which passes lines to my dummy IO) and an extended `StringIO` (which serves as the IO but also calls my filtering function). However, when I call `print()` inside of my processing function I get a `RecursionError` - which is not unexpected:

```
from io import StringIO
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

class StringIOWithCallback(StringIO):

    def __init__(self, callback, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.callback = callback

    def write(self, s):
        super().write(s)
        self.callback(s)

def filter_boring_stuff_out(line):
    if line.startswith('ignore'):
        return
    print(line)

my_io = StringIOWithCallback(filter_boring_stuff_out)

with redirect_stdout(my_io):
    thirdparty_code()
```

I wonder if it is possible to escape from the redirect, e.g. specifying the `file` parameter in `print()` function so that it prints to the actual standard output. I know that I can easily use the standard error stream:

```
import sys
print(line, file=sys.stderr)
```

But I specifically want to use the standard output. Is there a nice, pythonic way to do that?

Comment: You can just redirect sys.stdout (and std.err for that matter) through a function to filter stuff.  This is commonly done with logging.  Though from the looks of it you asked the question to answer it yourself.

Comment: How exactly do I do that? I am familiar with the practice of overwriting (or temporarily redirecting) `sys.stdout` to get the output as a string (e.g. for unit tests) and with people using custom logging functions of logger module (and filtering the logs by the level). However, neither directly adresses my problem of 'real-time' filtering as in the question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: And regarding the fact that I answered the question - is it wrong or discouraged to post this specific question due to me finding the answer while writing this up? I mean, I [read the piece](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and some posts on meta, but I don't have a strong feeling on whether this is a good Q&A. So far it served its purpose at least partialy - I have learned something from the other answer.

Comment: If you have an answer but believe there is a better way then just put your answer in the question and say something along the lines of you not believing it is the best way to do it.  If you come up with an answer over time then put it as an answer,  but if you have an answer off the bat than why ask the question? This is one of the reasons you can not mark an answer within a certain period after asking a question, people would just ask a question, put there answer, mark it as a solution, and call it a day. (even if it isn't a good solution).

Comment: Also to redirect `stdout` so `print` will be filtered see my answer below.

Comment: Not saying your solution is bad. Just used a general case :).  Good problem though.

Answer (score 4):

After having redirected the `stdout`, you can easily reset it thanks to `__stdout__` which saves the original value.

```
sys.stdout = redirected_stdout
...
...
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

If you continually find yourself switching these output streams, you ought to create a function to output to the redirected stream:

```
def redirect(*args):
    print(*args, file=redirected_file)

redirect(...)  # redirect this output
print(...)  # use standard stream
```

Comment: Thank you, the thing with `sys.__stdout__` is indeed useful to know!

Answer (score 1):

Once I have written my question I have realised that one simply needs to save the standard output object `sys.stdout` to a variable before invoking the redirect:

```
stdout = sys.stdout

def filter_boring_stuff_out(line):
    if line.startswith('ignore'):
        return
    print(line, file=stdout)
```

But as always - I would be happy to learn about other possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect `stdout` and ignore all messages that started with `ignore`. If you do it this way all `print`s will be intercepted. This will work better if you are trying to filter messages from code you don't have access to or don't want to change.

```
import sys
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

class Filter_Out:
    def __init__(self, *_, start=None, anywhere=None, end=None):
        self.last_ignore = False
        self.start = start
        self.anywhere = anywhere
        self.end = end
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
    def write(self, txt):
        if (self.start and txt.startswith(self.start)) or \
           (self.end and txt.endswith(self.end)) or \
           (self.anywhere and self.anywhere in txt):
            self.last_ignore = True
            return
        if self.last_ignore and txt == '\n':
            self.last_ignore = False
        else:
            self.terminal.write(txt)
    def flush(self):
        pass

with redirect_stdout(Filter_Out(start='ignore', anywhere='4')):
    print("test")
    print("test2")
    print("ignore: test2") # will not print because it started with ignore
    print("test1")
    print("test42") # will not print because it had 4 in it
```

Comment: Interesting, this highlights that there is no necessity of inheriting from IO. And the idea of saving the standard output inside of the init - which by definition will be executed before the redirect - is a nice addition.